# Python Matplotlib: iterate (with a for loop) to create multiples graphs on two plots with one being a subplot with shared y axis

Tags: python, matplotlib

As my code is fairly long (typical for newy), I placed here a simplified example of my issue.
From this code instead of getting a subplot graph of the datas of all the loops on figure 1, I only get the last one. I would be kind of you to help me to understand my mistake.

```
from numpy import *
from matplotlib.pyplot import *
import math
from pylab import *

i=0


for i in range (0,10):
    x=[i-1, i, i+1]
    y=[3*i, 3*i, 3*i]
    x1=[2-i, 3-i, 4-i]
    y1=[i, i ,i]
    plt.figure(1)
    f,(ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2, sharey=True)
    ax1.plot(x,y)
    ax2.plot(x1,y1)

    if i==9:  
        plt.savefig('test.jpg')
        plt.clf()

    plt.figure(7)
    plt.scatter(x1,y)
    if i==9:  

        plt.savefig('test2.jpg')
```

Answer (score 1):

Create the `figure` outside the loop, instead of re-creating it each iteration.

You may need to either break out your second plot into its own loop, or create a second `figure` outside the loop and specify which your subsequent call apply to.